# multiple app service plans with single (bizspark) subscription

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

We have BizSpark subscription with shared app service plan, where we are hosting our product. I need to host another version of the project for testing purpose, which fits into a free tier. I have checked the azure portals, but there is no provision to add a new service plan. does the BizSpark subscription support only one app service plan or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because an App Service services is an underlying component to other services, there isn't a simple way to directly create an App Service.

Since the only use case to create an App Service is to put something in it, the logic (I imagine) behind the Portals is that you create the resources you require and and it will create dependent resources within that process.

(Using the [New Portal](https://portal.azure.com))

In order to create a new App Service plan, presuming you are deploying a new Web App. Click on New, Web + Mobile and then Web App.

[image: Azure New > Web + Mobile]

When you click on Web App you will get this screen, if you fill in the details, and click App Service plan / Location at the bottom, you will be given the opportunity to select either an existing App Service or to create a new one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to create a new Web app and when asked for App Service create a new one .. or use Azure Resource Manager template to achieve this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/templates/.

Answer (score 0):

If it's another version of the App for testing purposes, why not use [Deployment Slots](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/)? Slots have their custom URL separate from the Production app, separated configuration, domain bindings, it's like an App inside an App. You'll be able (if you want) to even swap the content of the Production environment with the Testing one for example.

And you don't incur in any extra cost because it runs on the resources of the current App Service :)

Comment: Deployment slots wouldn't work as they are using the shared SKU and aren't available. Also performance testing on a live App Service Plan isn't advisable. (or testing in general, incase a hang etc consumes all resources and takes the live site offline)

Comment: Good catch, I missed the Free tier especification.